# $X^\emptyset$ versus $\emptyset^X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently read that there is a difference between $X^\emptyset$ and $\emptyset^X$. I was hoping that someone could explain why this is the case.

I have interpreted $B^A$ as, "*The set of all functions that have a domain of $A$ and a range of some subset of $B$*". More formally, I thought that:

$f \in B^A \leftrightarrow \exists Z ( Z \in P(B)\  \land f \subseteq A \times Z) $ <-- **Edit: $\color{red}{ \text{Here is the mistake} }$**

Additionally, we know that $\emptyset \times X = X \times \emptyset=\emptyset \times \emptyset = \emptyset$

It is vacuously true that $\forall x [\emptyset \subseteq x]$

Also, $P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$, which means that $\emptyset \in P(\emptyset)$ and, more generally, $\forall x [\emptyset \in P(x)]$

Using this information, consider the following two cases:

Case 1: $X^\emptyset$

Case 2: $\emptyset^X$

---

*Case 1*: $X^\emptyset$

Consider if $f$ is the **empty set function**.

Does a $Z$ satisfy the following formula? $Z \in P(X)\  \land \emptyset \subseteq \emptyset \times Z$

Sure! Let $Z=\emptyset$.

$\emptyset$ is an element of $P(X)$ and $\emptyset$ is a subset of $\emptyset \times \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Therefore, $X^\emptyset = \{ \emptyset \}$

---

*Case 2*: $\emptyset^X$

Consider if $f$ is the **empty set function**.

Does a $Z$ satisfy the following formula? $Z \in P(\emptyset)\  \land \emptyset \subseteq X\times Z$

Yup. If $Z=\emptyset$, then $\emptyset \in P(\emptyset)$ and $\emptyset \subseteq X \times \emptyset=\emptyset$

Therefore, $\emptyset^X=\{\emptyset\}$

---

So where exactly did I go wrong?

Comment: If $X\neq \emptyset$, then $\emptyset ^X$ does not compute, because there's nothing to assign to a given $x\in X$. Certainly $\emptyset ^X = \emptyset$.

Comment: @AlvinLepik I thought that a function had (among other things) the property that it was a subset of the cartesian product of the domain and codomain. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty set function isn´t a function from $X$ to $\varnothing$, because its domain is $\varnothing$, not $X$. So the problem is in case 2.

Moreover, your formula $f \in B^A \leftrightarrow \exists Z ( Z \in P(B)\  \land f \subseteq A \times Z)$ is not right, because any subset $f$ of $A\times B$ satisfies $\exists Z ( Z \in P(B)\  \land f \subseteq A \times Z)$ (putting $Z=B$).

A correct formula would be:

$f\in B^A \leftrightarrow (f\subseteq A\times B)\land(\forall a\exists b \;\langle a,b\rangle\in f)\land (\forall a\forall b\forall c\neg(b\neq c\land\langle a,b\rangle\in f\land \langle a,c\rangle\in f))$.

Where the first parenthesis says the domain and codomain are $A$ and $B$ respectively, the second one says that every element of $A$ has an image and the third one says no element of $A$ can have two different images.

Comment: Isn't the definition of a function that it is a subset of the cartesian product of the domain and codmain (with the property that any two elements with the same first component necessarily have the same second component)?

Comment: There is a third condition that says every element must have an image. I edited the answer to write a formal definition.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $X\neq\emptyset$.

Case 1. By definition $X^\emptyset = \{ f:\emptyset \to X\}$. At least one such map exists, we'll show it's unique. Suppose $f,g\in X^\emptyset$. Then $f,g$ coincide on the $\emptyset$ (vacuously), hence they must be equal.

Case 2. $\emptyset ^X = \{f:X\to\emptyset\}$. Suppose $\emptyset^X \neq\emptyset$. Then there exists $f:X\to \emptyset$. In particular $f(x) \in \emptyset$ for any $x\in X$. Therefore, $\emptyset ^X = \emptyset$.

Comment: cool contradiction in case 2~~